# Which one is more efficiency, static memory allocation or dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, sockets, memory, heap-memory

If I have to use 128/64 byte char array in c. Which one is more efficient static allocation of char array or dynamic memory allocation and why? Is this also valid if I have to allocate memory for 1kb or mare.

**I want to know which one is more efficient 1 or 2.** 
1. char array[128] or 
2. char *abc = malloc(128);

Comment: Define what do you mean by "efficient".

Comment: @Dayalrai That is simply not what 'efficient' means.

Comment: Efficient mean my code should run faster.

Comment: Until you have a code that spends the majority of its time within `malloc()`, I'd recommend to stop worrying about its efficiency. Heap and stack allocations serve two very different purposes, and in almost all contexts the purpose dictates which allocation scheme you use. For instance, you can't return a stack-allocated array from a function, so that's a purpose that would dictate a `malloc()`. Allocation is never a speed issue unless you keep allocating the same memory over and over again.

Comment: the question states 'static allocation' however, neither 1) nor 2) are expressing static allocation.

Comment: @Abhiteshkhatri: What about writing some test code and profile it, and then come back and dicuss the results here on SO?

Answer (score 3):

Static allocation, by which I assume you mean using the keyword `static`, takes place at link time. At runtime it is essentially zero cost, apart from a possible effect on program load time.

You can't get any more efficient than that.

**EDIT**

Stack allocation takes place by incrementing and decrementing a register. It is less efficient than `static` but considerably more efficient than using runtime memory allocation libraries.

Comment: No not static keyword. I want to know which one is more efficient 1 or 2.
1.  char array[128] or 2. char *abc = malloc(128);

Comment: There is nothing 'static' about that. It is *stack* allocation. See edit.

Comment: Interestingly it's not necessarily the case that a true static allocation is less costly at runtime than a `malloc()` allocation.  The first access to the static allocation could well involve a page fault, which is far from zero cost, and potentially less than the cost of a `malloc()` re-using a previously faulted-in part of the heap.  Not that this difference would ever matter in a practical sense.

Comment: That I see about the same probable as allocating on heap, then having your heap swapped out and then causing page fault accessing your data on heap.

Comment: @caf And about as probable as having a stack probe causing a page fault. It isn't something that is useful to consider as a difference between any of these three.

Comment: What **is** costly for a multithreaded process is the locking implicit in calls to `malloc()` (or `new`...) **and** the required corresponding calls to `free()` (or `delete`).  Stack memory already belongs to the thread running  on that stack.

Answer (score 1):

Stack allocation is more efficient than malloc() as it is simply an increment of the stack pointer, whereas malloc() involves the operating system and behind the scenes processing we don't have control of.  For relatively small variables use the stack unless there is some other reason not to, like you need the memory to exist after your function goes out of scope. Use dynamic allocation for very large variables to avoid stack overflow problems.  What is very large?  Depends on your CPU and stack size. For windows work I put anything less than a few K on the stack. For a small embedded CPU like a AVR, this can be 255 or less -- again depending on your allocated stack size.